# (lyrics) I'm a-pushin' and a-shovin' it

Tags: sentence-meaning, lyrics

This is one of the lyrics which from the song "Young Lust" of Aerosmith.

I've already known what "push and shove" means, but what is the usage of "a-xxing"? How can I understand the whole sentence?

I know it's a song in which the words may not grammarically right, what I really want is to understand its meaning.

The part of the lyrics go like this:

> Young lust
>   No don't need one in the oven
>   Young lust
>   **I'm a-pushin' and a-shovin' it**
>
> Young lust
>   Come on now I just can't wait
>   Are you fishin or you gonna cut bait
>   Everybody body doin' it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many songs, it's written in a non-standard dialect; in this case, a rural American one in which the continuous ("I'm pushing") often rendered as "I'm a-pushin'".

As far as I know, there's no difference in meaning: I think the variant form is just used for rhythmic effect (not just in song: also in story-telling).

See for example the start of the ninth paragraph of [Huckleberry Finn](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm#c1): "I set down again, a-shaking all over". But in the previous paragraph he uses the standard form "she kept pecking at me".